# How to add or subtract a number to a date?

Tags: r, date

I would like to know how to add or substract a number to a date.
Here is an example of a date I have to use :

```
"2000-01-01"
```

I would like to add 1 year to this date to get :

```
"2001-01-01"
```

I tried `date + 1` but it doesn't work since it's 1 is an integer.
It is probably simple but I would like to know how to do it.
Also, is it possible to do it with the months and/or the days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for such operations I usually like to use the `lubridate` package.
Here's how I would do it :

```
library("lubridate")

date <- as.Date("2000-01-01")

date %m+% years(1)
date %m+% months(1)
date %m+% days(1)
```

So in your case :

```
date %m+% years(1)
[1] "2001-01-01"
```

Edit : I suggest you use `%m+%` instead of a simple `+` since the former:

> "add and substract months to a date without exceeding the last day of
>   the new month."*

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/%25m%2B%25

Note : you can also use `%m-%`.